# UILabel with viewWithTag - (text not appearing)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

have a UITableViewCell, to which I add a label on it with tag 1000.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1000];

if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

then

```
 UILabel *labelName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000]
 labelName.text = @"test".
```

When I run, the cell is empty. Any advice?

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you specify a tag of 1000. typo i'm assuming?

Comment: It is just mistake man, cause I copy this code from internet. Let's assume that the tag 1000 and not 5000. Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: I can't see you're adding a label anywhere. You're just casting UITableViewCell to a UILabel which is incorrect at the first place..

Comment: I added a label from StoryBoard and provide it the tag number. is it not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"]` and `[cell viewWithTag:5000]` are returning something other than **nil**.

If they are, be sure to do it in this order:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Try to reuse the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];

    //If you can't reuse, instantiate the cell 
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];
    }

    //Now that you have your cell, find the label 
    UILabel *labelName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5000];

    //Check if the label exists just in case 
    if (labelName) {
        //And set the text
        [labelName setText:@"test"];
    }
}
```

Comment: @leecan Have you checked if the label identifier on your cell is really **5000**?

Comment: And the `identifier` of your cell is **@"ChecklistItem"** (or whatever you are checking)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem could also be that you aren't using a unique tag number. Meaning that something in your view controller scene could possibly have the same tag number that you have defined on another object.

For example, for me, I had a UITableViewCell which had a tag # of 0 and a UILabel with a tag # of 0 and another UILabel with a tag # of 1. This caused problems and made it to where tag #1 wouldn't display at all. I could see the text when I clicked on the row -- but the data wouldn't show when the row wasn't clicked on.

When I changed the tag numbers of both UILabels, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue already solved, my application was working very fine on iPhone, so I decide to make it universal. I copy all view controller to iPad storyboard. And I start doing some change on iPad storyboard.

Whatever I add/delete on iPad storyboard, didn't make any change as the main interface was iphone and the reason was that I didn't change the main interface for iPad, so while running on iPad, I was using the storyboard of iPhone.