# Auto Layout: Lining up two UILabels in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I'm new to iOS development and it seems that Auto Layout is the most confusing part to me.

I have a UITableViewCell which is a dynamic prototype.

On the cell, in the storyboard scene, I have created:

{ [UILABEL]  [UILABEL] } <-- TableViewCell

I want the two labels to be aligned next to each other.

The first UILabel is a date (Month/Day) and the second UILabel is a title.

I know that the title will be too large. However, it still needs to sit next to the Date Label with only a tiny space between them.

Ex. 12/01   Example Title

I have literally tried everything in the Storyboard - from trying to allow Xcode to automatically "suggest the constraints" to creating my own by setting the right, left, and bottom constraints. As well as, configuring the content hugging property for the title label to be 1000 for vertical and horizontal.

The date label shows up correctly. However, the title label doesn't show up at all... other than some buggy white specs on the side. =(

If I press and hold down on the row, I can see the title in the background behind the date label and across the entire row.

I did configure the text of each row programmatically in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, by doing this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// get the label objects of the cell
UILabel *dateLabelOfCell = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
UILabel *titleLabelOfCell = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

dateLabelOfCell.text = date;
titleLabelOfCell.text = title;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

Looks like the label text is being set. The data is just not showing up. So, I looked more into setting the cell labels using viewwithtag and I found that other people were running into this issue:

[UILabel with viewWithTag - (text not appearing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888469/uilabel-with-viewwithtag-text-not-appearing)

However, none of their solutions work. Any ideas why the first UILabel shows up and the second one doesn't? I only see the second UILabel if I go to click on the row.

Answer (score 0):

I determined the issue.

The reason why the 2nd UILabel wasn't showing up wasn't due to the Auto Layout at all.

The problem was because I was using 0 and 1 for my tag numbers. So, I changed both the tag numbers in my storyboard file and updated the code to match and they both appeared.

I believe the reason using 0 caused problems and interfered is because the tableviewcell's default tag number was 0 as well.

So, make sure the tag numbers you use are unique.